# OpenVpn Windows clients trafic is routed but not Linux

Tags: linux, windows, vpn, openvpn, ubuntu-18.04

I am new to OpenVPN. I have set up an OpenVPN server which clients can connect to on Ubuntu 18.04. I have pushed routes so that all network traffic runs through the server. Windows clients can connect and they have access to all local resources and the internet. When I connect with a Linux client I only have access to the server 10.8.0.1 no internet and can't see other servers or clients on the local network. 
Here are my config files. I have removed the comments.

server.conf

```
port 1194  
proto tcp
;proto udp
;dev tap
dev tun
;dev-node MyTap
ca ca.crt
cert server.crt
key server.key  # This file should be kept secret
dh dh.pem
;topology subnet
server 10.8.0.0 255.255.255.0
ifconfig-pool-persist /var/log/openvpn/ipp.txt
;server-bridge 10.8.0.4 255.255.255.0 10.8.0.50 10.8.0.100
;server-bridge
push "route 10.8.0.1 255.255.255.255"
push "route 10.8.0.0 255.255.255.0"
push "route 172.168.0.21 255.255.255.255"
push "route 172.168.0.0 255.255.254.0"
;client-config-dir ccd
;client-config-dir ccd
;route 10.9.0.0 255.255.255.252
;learn-address ./script
push "redirect-gateway def1"
push "dhcp-option DNS 172.168.0.20"
push "dhcp-option DOMAIN bdlfire.local"
push "dhcp-option SEARCH bdlfire.local"
client-to-client
;duplicate-cn
keepalive 10 120
tls-auth ta.key 0 # This file is secret
key-direction 0
cipher AES-256-CBC
auth SHA256
;compress lz4-v2
;push "compress lz4-v2"
;comp-lzo
;max-clients 100
user nobody
group nogroup
persist-key
persist-tun
status /var/log/openvpn/openvpn-status.log
;log         /var/log/openvpn/openvpn.log
;log-append  /var/log/openvpn/openvpn.log
verb 3
;mute 20
explicit-exit-notify 0
```

Windows config client.ovpn

```
client
;dev tap
dev tun
;dev-node MyTap
proto tcp
;proto udp
remote xx.xx.xxx.xxx 1194
;remote my-server-2 1194
;remote-random
nobind
;user nobody
;group nobody
persist-key
persist-tun
;http-proxy-retry # retry on connection failures
;http-proxy [proxy server] [proxy port #]
;mute-replay-warnings
cert client3.crt
key client3.key
remote-cert-tls server
tls-auth ta.key 0
key-direction 1
cipher AES-256-CBC
auth SHA256
verb 3
;mute 20
redirect-gateway
```

Linux config client.conf

```
client
;dev tap
dev tun
proto tcp
;proto udp
remote xx.xx.xxx.xxx 1194
;remote my-server-2 1194
;remote-random
resolv-retry infinite
nobind
;user nobody
;group nobody
persist-key
persist-tun
;http-proxy-retry # retry on connection failures
;http-proxy [proxy server] [proxy port #]
;mute-replay-warnings
ca ca.crt
cert client1.crt
key client1.key
remote-cert-tls server
tls-auth ta.key 0
key-direction 1
cipher AES-256-CBC
auth SHA256
verb 3
;mute 20
redirect-gateway
```

Any help would be much appreciated. Thanks Carl

I have tried running the route command and got this response.

```
    Kernel IP routing table
Destination     Gateway     Genmask         Flags Metric Ref  Use Iface
0.0.0.0         10.8.0.5    128.0.0.0       UG    0      0      0 tun0
default         _gateway    0.0.0.0         UG    20600  0      0 wlp7s0
10.8.0.0        10.8.0.5    255.255.255.0   UG    0      0      0 tun0
10.8.0.1        10.8.0.5    255.255.255.255 UGH   0      0      0 tun0
10.8.0.5        0.0.0.0     255.255.255.255 UH    0      0      0 tun0
67.89.211.183   _gateway    255.255.255.255 UGH   0      0      0 wlp7s0
128.0.0.0       10.8.0.5    128.0.0.0       UG    0      0      0 tun0
link-local      0.0.0.0     255.255.0.0     U     1000   0      0 wlp7s0
172.168.0.0     10.8.0.5    255.255.254.0   UG    0      0      0 tun0
172.168.0.21    10.8.0.5    255.255.255.255 UGH   0      0      0 tun0
192.168.0.0     0.0.0.0     255.255.255.0   U     600    0      0 wlp7s0
```

Is that what i should expect?

Answer (score 0):

Your client configurations don't use `pull` to get the values pushed from the server. Maybe the Windows version uses `pull` by default.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I tried adding pull route in the client conf but the client would not start.

Comment: Do you have error message why it doesn't start? Try starting OpenVPN manually with higher values for `--verb`.

Answer (score 0):

The OpenVPN Client requires root or Administrator privileges. The community client installation on windows is automatically adding OpenVPN as service, enabling it to push routes.

On some Linux distributions OpenVPN as client isn't started as root and therefore isn't able to push the routes accordingly upon connect.

You can confirm this by querying the routes of your client Linux box when connected to OpenVPN (using the `route` program) and the routes to push aren't showing up.

Comment: I have added my routes to the original question. I this as you expected

Comment: Sadly not. Can you try to run it as root and test again? Just to know that this is not the mistake.